# PHP bindParam variable error

Tags: php, web-services, pdo, bindparam

In my web service I have a problem with `bindParams`. Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sless WHERE ST_CONTAINS(data.area, Point(:query))");
$stmt->bindParam(':query', $queryText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

but `:query` variable isnt correctly adapted this code.

When I echo `$queryText` it gives `29.029087,40.990361` perfectly. But in the code it's not working. By the way when I write `29.029087,40.990361` latitude and longitude instead of the variable `:query` my code working perfectly. Here is the code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sless WHERE ST_CONTAINS(data.area, Point(29.029087,40.990361))");
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try both coordinate separately `Point(:lat,:lng)`

Comment: bindValue() ...

Comment: @KyleThomas nothing changed

Comment: @Musa yes i think comma give this error. But i'm new on webservices so. i can not handle 2 varaible. Is this the error solution?

Comment: Just split the query into lat and lng   `list($lat, $lng) = split(',', $queryText);`

Comment: wow. you are great. Thank you So much. @Musa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try both coordinate separately

```
list($lat, $lng) = split(',', $queryText);
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sless WHERE ST_CONTAINS(data.area, Point(:lat,:lng))");
$stmt->bindParam(':lat', $lat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lng', $lng, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probabily because the function **Point()** needs two numeric params like this:

> Point(1, 2)

And you are giving just one string param like this:

> Point("1, 2")

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html